# How to create a disabled Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server

I'm pretty sure I can't do this, but asking nevertheless.
My requirement is a bit 'strange' but bear with me.

Situation:

- table A has UQ on field x
- table B has FK towards table A.x

I want to delete all values from A (and hence B) but they may contain A LOT of data.

To do this I've got a stored procedure that will loop over all tables that FK towards A (recursively) and (temporarily) remove all FK's. Once done, I `TRUNCATE TABLE` every table involved and then restore all FK's again.

In a way, I'm doing a cascaded truncate.

This has worked great for a long time and is much faster than doing the `DELETE` in the right order since it's pretty much a couple of meta-data operations only that are minimally logged so I can even do it in 1 not-so-big transaction.

And then I met the following situation:

- The UQ on table A(X) got disabled for some reason
- The system then automagically disabled the FK from B to A on (x), which makes sense as there is no UQ to refer to anymore.

When my stored procedure now tries to empty A (and the tables referencing it), it finds the FK disabled, drops it, truncates table A and tries to recreate the FK but fails because it has no corresponding (enabled) UQ on table A.

I tried to use `WITH NOCHECK` but alas. (SQL 2012)

My best solution for now is to create a dummy UQ on table A(x), create the FK and then drop the dummy UQ again in case it finds there is no applicable UQ available. It works, but I was wondering if I could skip all the extra checks and code.

Example code:

```
-- cleanup
IF OBJECT_ID('B') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE B
IF OBJECT_ID('A') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE A

GO
--setup
CREATE TABLE A ( a int IDENTITY(1, 1), x int CONSTRAINT UQ_A_x UNIQUE, y varchar(100))

INSERT A (x, y)
VALUES (10, 'A'),
       (20, 'B')

CREATE TABLE B (b int IDENTITY(1, 1), x int CONSTRAINT FK_B_x_A FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES A (x), z varchar(100))

INSERT B (x, z)
VALUES (10, 'tralalala'),
       (20, 'blablabla')

GO
-- CASCADED TRUNCATE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE B DROP CONSTRAINT FK_B_x_A
    TRUNCATE TABLE B
    TRUNCATE TABLE A
    ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B_x_A FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES A (x)
COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO
-- what if... 
ALTER INDEX UQ_A_x ON A DISABLE

-- no longer works, even with NOCHECK:
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE B DROP CONSTRAINT FK_B_x_A
    TRUNCATE TABLE B
    TRUNCATE TABLE A
    ALTER TABLE B WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B_x_A FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES A (x) 
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I followed this to a point but then got lost. Can you post some dummy table definitions for A and B (including FK and UQ) and explain what you are trying to do. I just can't quite follow this.

Comment: @SeanLange added list of operations involved. It works fine until the index gets disabled, after that I'm no longer able to add the foreign key. Again, I understand why it refuses to do so, I just wished there was an easy way around.

Comment: You can't create any constraints disabled. Creating them `WITH NOCHECK` merely skips checking existing data and still results in an enabled constraint. You can create a constraint and disable it atomically in a transaction, but this will still not allow you to get around the prerequisites for the constraint in the create. Personally, I wouldn't bother with recreating the disabled constraints at all -- yes, you do lose them that way, but if the constraint is disabled for an extended time (not during maintenance) it's probably no longer relevant anyway. You could also just detect and bail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pretty much as expected, it can't be done. 
Thanks to all commenters for their feedback.